# What are window-managers with good features for power-users?

Tags: linux, productivity, window-manager

Most window-managers copy the ideas of windows and MacOSX these days. But some have innovative ideas, that make the life much easier and the work faster done.

I used long time [Fluxbox](http://www.fluxbox.org/) - it was the first wm I learned to know, that allow me to configure keys and have control about the sizing of applications. Putting windows in a window-group and let them share the same titlebar makes the tab-feature of some applications unneeded - tabbing in the WM is the far better solution.

Recently I dropped Fluxbox - because I tried the [awesome-wm](http://awesome.naquadah.org/). That makes life even better with this tag-concept. I can run applications in fullscreen without borders and without title-bar, that saves much space on the screen (good for my 8-inch-netbook-screen). I can tile the windows if needed and group tags together as I wish. I don't think I even use all features of awesome yet.

I want to know, what window-managers do you know with cool innovative features, that might change the world (at least the world of superusers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like the idea of a tiling window manager you should definitely check out [dwm](http://dwm.suckless.org). I found the configuration to be far less daunting than that of awesome-wm (though you do have to recompile after a reconfiguration). Here are some of my favorite features:

- The ability to start programs with a certain tag is what really did it for me (not sure if this feature is also available in awesome).
- Being able to pipe [conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net) into dwm and have it displayed in the status bar is quite useful as well.
- Being able to map hotkeys without the need for any external program running in the background.
- Functionality can be extended through the use of [patches](http://dwm.suckless.org/patches/) provided by the community.

  [Dmenu](http://tools.suckless.org/dmenu) means you'll never need to take your hands off the keyboard again.

Comment: Tags, configurable hotkeys and starting applications with the keyboard are all features of awesome. I could be wrong, but wasn't awesome a fork of dwm?

Comment: No; while they are similar dwm takes a more minimalistic approach using only a single C header file for configuration that is then compiled into the application itself instead of interpreting Lua configuration files (as in awesome). Its really just a matter of taste I suppose if you're not worried about the extra dependencies.

Comment: +1 for dwm.  It's a bit of a pain to set up if you want to use it inside a gnome session, but still the most comfortable WM i've used.

Comment: "Being able to map hotkeys without the need for any external program running in the background."  This sounds nice, but is there any practical advantage to this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for X window managers, [this is a good place to start.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_window_manager#Popular_X_window_managers)

Comment: Also check out [xwinman](http://xwinman.org). It's also got a nice page of historical window managers for those with more specialized tastes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want heavily customized window-manager, try [fvwm](http://www.fvwm.org). You can even use perl to do scripting in the rc file.

Comment: I agree with CyberSnoopy fvwm is by far the most customizable window manager!!